# Replace image with video in gallery

Tags: html, css

This is the code I'm using for the gallery, bootstrap based template

```
<div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">
  <div class="gallery img d-flex align-items-end" style="background-image: url(images/gallery/leopardshark.jpg);">
    <a href="images/gallery/leopardshark.jpg" class="icon image-popup d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <span class="icon-expand"></span></a>
    <div class="desc w-100 px-4">
      <div class="text w-100 mb-3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the background image with a video, is there away to do that and make it autoplay in all browsers? I can get mp4s to work in Safari if I just replace the image url.

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: And no, you can not just replace an actual background image, with a video. For a video, you need an actual video element. How to get that positioned in the background behind the rest of content (if any) - that's something you should do some research on first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by replacing the img with:

```
<video autoplay>
  <source src="/path" type="video/mp4">
error message
</video>
```

This will autoplay in Firefox but not in Chrome(they blocked it). So you will need to also use something like this if you don't want to add controls:

```
$('.class_name').on('load', function(){
  $('video').load();
  $('video').play();
});
```